# Can we use VMDK for FCI on SQL Servers?

Tags: sql-server, configuration, clustering, storage

Can I share a VMDK among 2 nodes for an active passive setup for a SQL Server Failover Cluster setup?

Most of the articles I see mention to use RDM's, however we use Veeam backup for the environment and it doesn't support RDM's.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot reliably use VMDK files for shared storage in VMware-virtualized Windows Server Failover Clustering.  RDMs (Raw device mappings) are the only supported method of provisioning disks in this scenario. Use RDMs in physical compatibility mode (pass-through RDM). You cannot use virtual disks or RDMs in virtual compatibility mode (non-pass-through RDM) for shared storage.  You *can* use VMDKs for the non-shared drives.  See [Setup for Failover Clustering and Microsoft Cluster Service](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-51-setup-mscs.pdf) from VMware for more details.

Since you have Veeam, you should use the SQL Server backup tools included with that package; see [Veeam's help center for vSphere backup and restore](https://helpcenter.veeam.com/evaluation/backup/vsphere/en/sql_backup_and_restore.html) for more details.

Comment: Technically you can use them for CIAB (cluster in a box), but let's be honest that's pretty *&%^ pointless for a HA solution. If you use Hyper-V, you can use shared vhdx for clusters if the hyper-v storage is csv.

Comment: Yes, @Sean you can use them for test purposes.  You can even do it in production if you're totally dumb, and don't realize that two VMDKs named the same aren't really one disk.  Ask me how annoyed I was the first time I saw that in production.

Comment: The symptoms were the disk would sometimes have a particular folder, and other times, no folder.  Our server management team (outsourced) had *copied* a vmdk to the other cluster member, and configured the 2nd node to use that vmdk.

Comment: lol - I feel like we've all been in a situation like that. I know a few places that saw CIAB and swore up and down they didn't need RDM... then a host went down and they wondered where the HA went.